leaf switches and STP issue
I have a situation where I need to connect leaf switches in the following manner.
why we are doing this? we are connecting two different sites,kind of a cross site connection.
The red cross mark is blocked by STP. the vpc domain is 50 both sites. 1 and 2 are vpc peer. 3 and 4 are vpc peer.
Is there anyway I can get these ports unblocked.? Servers connected to 3and4 in site 1 are not able to go cross site and connect to servers on 3and4 on site2.

Basically, STP (any implementation) detects multiple connections between bridges (switches) and block redundant links. It doesn't block all links.
You need to debug your STP setup: check the spanning tree status on each port and the switch logs. Remember that RSTP and the MSTP with the common instance only are completely VLAN agnostic: you need to run all interlinks with identical VLANs.
If you want to utilize more than a single interlink, then you need to configure multiple MSTP instances and group VLANs into them, or use RPVST+. Alternatively, set up a multi-chassis LAG and forget about STP mostly.

Hi Zac, thanks for this. Yeah i too feel will need to do a debug. And yes all interlinks are identical vlan. Those two cross-site link are 60km apart and we do q-in-q l2 tunnel.

MST CIST is not "VLAN agnostic". Any VLAN not assigned to a specific instance belongs to the common instance. In an MST region, all devices must have the same vlan/instance configuration.

@Ricky Poorly phrased - I tried to point out that MSTP in default config is VLAN agnostic.
